# Any idea about : System.RequiredFeatureMissingException: Object 'Group Subscription' not supported

Tags: apex, chatter

Do any one have idea about this exception? Or any one experienced the same issue?
[image]

Group Subscription is not a standard object.
I read  to this doc https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_exception_methods.htm

it says `RequiredFeatureMissing     A Chatter feature is required for code that has been deployed to an organization that does not have Chatter enabled.`

The error is coming in production (Unlimited Edition) but not in the full sandbox.

Also the chatter is enabled.

Comment: Is your destination org chatter enabled ?

Comment: Yes ! Chatter is Enabled in destination org.

Comment: compare chatter settings in both Instances ..

Comment: Hi Mohit, I really appreciate your help. I figured out the issue and it is resolved now. The Object Group Subscription was supported in API 25.0 .

Comment: Glad to here .Post as solution buddy and we will upvote so that keeps helping others without pulling hairs again trying to do R&D :)

Comment: Sure.Go ahead !

Comment: well ,I asked you to post solution you discovered :).I will upvote