# System.RequiredFeatureMissingException: Object 'GroupSubscription' is not supported

Tags: apex, managed-package, appexchange

I have developed an app which can mass clone any sObject, which clones the records using the batch process and it runs dynamically(object and its field are fetched dynamically), Its working fine when the whole package is unmanaged but as soon as I make it managed, when I try to mass clone any record I get the above error

> "System.RequiredFeatureMissingException: Object 'GroupSubscription' is
>   not supported. One or more features must be enabled to access this
>   object."

Can anyone please share any insights regarding this, like reason or any available solution for the same.

Comment: Not your scenario but fyi [Any idea about : System.RequiredFeatureMissingException: Object 'Group Subscription' not supported](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/34118/any-idea-about-system-requiredfeaturemissingexception-object-group-subscript).

Comment: FWIW, when I look at the [Object Reference](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/object_reference/object_reference.pdf), I don't see `GroupSubscription` listed as a standard object. It's possible that it may have been deprecated and replaced by another object. Once you've applied your namespacing, that issue may be of more relevance than when the package was unmanaged.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @crmprogdev, API deprecation is likely the issue. How far back did you set your API for compatibility? The [same issue](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/34118/any-idea-about-system-requiredfeaturemissingexception-object-group-subscript) was resolved in another post:

```
Hi Mohit, I really appreciate your help. 
I figured out the issue and it is resolved now. 
The Object Group Subscription was supported in API 25.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your destination enabled with Chatter ?
If yes you can compare settings in them.

See the detailed explanation here :
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/packaging_chatter.htm